# Elastic Defend - file hashes collection

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have deployed several Elastic Agents for data collection for SOC. Elastic Agents have added intergation Elastic Defend, which is collecting (not only) information about creation of files. I can see those events in ElasticSearch but i need to collect also sha256 hashes of these files. How can I configure Elastic Defend integration so all events will also contain those hashes?

I have tried setting of various integrations through Kibana but nothing seems work.